# How to get notifications that have Edge date property greater than last visited date in Titan using Gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan, rexster

I'm having user vertices which have incoming Notification edges as follows:

code am using to get notifications

```
g.v(17929472).outE('Notification')
```

Response I'm getting :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "results": [
    {
      "Type": "UserReaction",
      "PostedDate": "2016-04-15T09:03:42.8391677Z",
      "NotificationInitiatedByVertexId": "2304",
      "_id": "c7bb4-aoagw-sgl-aoao0",
      "_type": "edge",
      "_outV": 17929472,
      "_inV": 17929728,
      "_label": "Notification"
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.5.0",
  "queryTime": 15.310751
}
```

Whenever user view the notification i'm saving the last seen date and want to use that date to get all notification that is present after that date.

I've tried :

```
g.v((5124096).outE).outE.has('PostedDate',T.gte, 2016-04-15T07:52:31.6979843Z).inV
```

but it is giving error.

Comment: Your code indicates that you're using TinkerPop 2.x. I strongly suggest switching to TinkerPop 3+ instead, which is a complete rewrite with a much more powerful API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostedDate` appears to be returned as a String. Consider defining `PostedDate` in your schema definition as a `Long` instead, and then do the `T.gte` comparison with a `Long` value.

Comment: do i need to delete previous test data or will it work if i just add another property as PostedDateLong along with existing properties?

Comment: just go ahead and try it

Comment: I've added one edge with following properties
Type: WallPostNotification
PostedDate: 2016-04-15T15:01:21.1012501Z
PostedDateLong: 635963292811012501
NotificationInitiatedByVertexId: 17928960
_id: c7lmo-1s0-sgl-aoetc


g.E.has('PostedDateLong',T.gte, 0)

Comment: but the query... g.E.has('PostedDateLong',T.gte, 0)  is returning empty set.